# Weird EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash related with setter/getter in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

Could someone explain why following my code crash? Crash happenes inside the block in foo method.
I've got EXC_BAD_ACCESS or "error for object: double free". And I also got "-[NSObject description]: message sent to deallocated instance" when I set "Enable Zombie Objects" ON.

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSObject *obj;
@end

@implementation ViewController

// just adding button
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    [btn setTitle:@"test" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100);
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:btn];
}

// fired by button
- (void)btnAction:(id)sender {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        [self foo];
    }
}

// I want to understand this method
- (void)foo {
    NSLog(@"foo");

    self.obj = NSObject.new;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSLog(@"%@", [[self obj] description]);  // sometimes crash happenes here with a message "-[NSObject description]: message sent to deallocated instance"
    });
}

@end
```

Looks like self.obj is deallocated between [self obj] and [obj description]. But I'm not sure why.

I think the object from [self obj] should be owned by it's scope and should not be deallocated even if self.obj = NSObject.new is executed at the same time on other threads.
Is my understanding wrong?

I'm testing on iOS 7.0.4 with ARC. Thanks!

Comment: Is this your real code?  `[self obj] description]` doesn't look like it would compile.

Comment: Why are you doing the logging in the background?

Comment: @AaronBrager I'm sorry it was my mistake. updated post!

Comment: @rmaddy There is no meanings. My real code is more complicated. I just tried to make simplest sample code in order to figure this out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a for loop that is calling your `-foo` method, so self.obj is rapidly getting set to new values. Each time this happens, you're executing code asynchronously that is accessing your (`nonatomic`) property. But even if it is always getting a correct value for that property when being accessed from multiple threads, the main thread is very likely setting the property to a new value before the background thread finishes using the previous value of the property. And once the property gets changed to a new value, it releases the previous object that was assigned to it.

Since you're accessing your property from multiple threads, you want it to be atomic, not nonatomic, so change your property to this:

```
@property (strong) NSObject *obj;
```

`atomic` is the default. It is probably also safer to do the following with your asynchronous block:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    NSObject *obj = self.obj;
    if (self.obj) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [obj description]);
    }
});
```

You should no longer see a crash if you do this, because `obj` will always either be `nil` or a valid object with a strong reference to it inside the block.

However, you probably won't get the results you expect from this. For each execution of your asynchronous block, it's not guaranteed that you'll get the subsequent instances of `NSObject` that you're creating. There might be times where it executes your block where `obj` is the same object both times, and where you never see some of the objects that were created. This is because your asynchronous block isn't getting the instance set immediately before you made the call to invoke the block, it's getting it from the property. If you want this to use the instance set immediately prior, you must do something like the following:

```
__block NSObject *obj = NSObject.new;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    NSLog(@"%@", [obj description]);
});
```

This should always use the instance that you created specifically for that invocation of the asynchronous block.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yeah I understand atomic fixes this problem. But I still can't understand why my code can crash.  This is just a sample code to reproduce my real problem. So I'm not expecting same obj is used in self.obj = NSObject.new; and [[self obj] description]. But I'm expecting same object should be used between [self obj] and [obj description], is it wrong?

Comment: The problem is most likely occurring because between getting the object with `[self obj]` and calling the `-description` method on it, it is getting deallocated because the property is getting set to a new value. In fact who knows what you might get since the property is `nonatomic` and being accessed from multiple threads. By the time you get the value from the property, it might have already been deallocated, and you're getting an old value because, again, you're accessing a `nonatomic` property from multiple threads concurrently.

Comment: Are you saying all nonatomic properties can return deallocated object? I'm seeing reallySetProperty method in http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-532.2/runtime/Accessors.subproj/objc-accessors.mm . But I don't see any reason which nonatomic property will return deallocated object in it.

Comment: Probably wouldn't return a deallocated object, but the object that gets returned could get deallocated very soon after it is returned. Look at the implementation of `objc_getProperty_non_gc` in there as well, looking at what it does if it is not atomic. When it's not atomic, the return value is not retained and autoreleased, meaning it could be deallocated at any moment.

Comment: Umm, could you take a look at this screen shot http://cl.ly/image/0z1C0k1t1w3m ? obj is returned via objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue. Though I couldn't find the implementation of this method, I think obj should be registered to auto release pool and held by end of this runloop. I feel it doesn't make sense obj is deallocated between [self obj] and [obj description].

Comment: No, take another look at the method, the return happens at this point: `if (!atomic) return *slot;`, not at the autorelease point. So it is not retained and autoreleased, it is simply returned. That's why it's not thread-safe, because a different thread could do something that could result in it getting deallocated before you have a chance to retain it or use it. That's why it needs to be atomic if it is going to be accessed from multiple threads.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I see. You're right. So, in general, a getter of nonatomic property can return deallocated object if its setter is called from other threads. So we should make it atomic or do other things like taking a lock in order to prevent crash in this case. My understanding is correct?

Comment: That's correct. You should never access a `nonatomic` property from multiple threads unless you specifically do your own locking. And even if a property is `atomic`, it's often still a good idea to do some additional synchronization work, because just because a property is `atomic` doesn't mean that the data structure being accessed is thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue is caused by the `nonatomic` property attribute as you are re-allocating `self.obj` 100 times I think there is a possibility of the background thread reading a partially reallocated object pointer.

Please try with:

```
@property (atomic, strong) NSObject *obj;
```

Comment: `atomic` is the default, so you don't specify it, you just leave off `nonatomic` and it will be atomic. Also there's still the problem that the background logging will likely see the same value for `obj` multiple times in a row, and not see some of the values of `obj`, because the background logging is always accessing from the property, instead of getting the instance set specifically for that invocation of the block.

Comment: @Gavin `strong` is also the default, but you specified it in your answer.

Comment: @AaronBrager, true, but `strong` or `weak` from what I've seen is generally specified. But `atomic` is rarely specified.

Comment: @trojanfoe Thanks for your response! Could you explain more details of "there is a possibility of the background thread reading a partially reallocated object pointer"?

Comment: @taichino With a `nonatomic` setter/getter, it's possible that ARC is still doing its work when you create a new version of `obj` and that the getter will get the pointer to an already deallocated instance.

Comment: @trojanfoe umm, I'm seeing reallySetProperty method in opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-532.2/runtime/… . But I don't see any reason which nonatomic property will return deallocated object in it. can nonatomic property really return deallocated instance?

Answer (score 0):

By the time the background logging is being done, `self.obj` could be different or in the middle of being changed.

Use a local variable like this:

```
- (void)foo {
    NSLog(@"foo");

    NSObject *val = [NSObject new];
    self.obj = val;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSLog(@"%@", val);
    });
}
```

This will avoid threading issues and ensure the `NSLog` logs the proper instance.

Comment: You're missing the `*` that you need for val to be a pointer to an `NSObject`. Also the block will make a copy of `val` because you're not using the `__block` keyword. You'll see that implementation in my answer.

Comment: Fixed the typo - thanks. This whole question and its code seems to be extremely contrived.

Comment: I agree, it's not something someone would really do. But if he is trying to expand on this to do something in the background on 100 different objects, he should know that his code has that flaw.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks for your response! I understand your code is better. But I want to know why "self.obj could be different or in the middle of being changed" can happen.

According to reallySetProperty in this code http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-532.2/runtime/Accessors.subproj/objc-accessors.mm, old value is released after new value is assigned to ivar. 

So if new val is assigned before [self obj], it's okay.
And also if new val is assigned after [self obj], old value is owned it's scope and should not be deallocated, I think.

Is this wrong?